# Java Stream: Filter list 1 based on the objects present in list 2

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to filter a list based on the values present in another list. I've gone through other similar questions and am trying to use that to achieve me objective but am unable to do so.

List 1 consists of object of class `CarModel`(L1)

```
public class CarModel   {
  private String year;

  private String model;

}
```

List 2 consists of object of class `CarData`(L2)

```
public class CarData   {
  private OffsetDateTime date;

  private List<CarDetails> carDetails;

}


public class CarDetails   {
  private String owner;

  private List<Cars> cars = null;
}


public class Car   {
  private String modelName;

  private String dealership;

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is filter `list2` based on the `Car.modelName` of `list1` matching with the `CarModel.model` of `list2`.

*For example:*

list 1 consists of 3 objects:

```
carModel1 = { year: 2019, model: BMW-500-7S-150-Z100 }
carModel2 = { year: 2019, model: MERCEDES-700-7S-350-Z100 }
carModel3 = { year: 2018, model: AUDI-100-Q6-350-Z100 }
```

list 2 contains the following object:

```
CarData = {
   date: 2-6-2021,
   carDetails: [
   {
     owner: John,
     cars: [ {
          modelName: BMW-500-7S-*-Z100, 
          dealership: Nevada
       },
       {
          modelName:MERCEDES-700-7S-*-Z100, 
          dealership: Daytona
       }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

So post filtering, list 1 would not contain `c3` since that model does not match with `modelName` in `CarData`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample input and the sample result you're trying to get?

Comment: What should your result be? A list of filtered `Car`s?

Comment: @JanezKuhar the result should be a list of filtered Car Model,

Comment: Use a `Set` to collect those `modelName`s, then filter according to the set.

Comment: @Mureinik have added example for more clarification.

Comment: @zhh can you give an example

Comment: list 2 contains a list of CarData object

Comment: Does your `list2` contain a different number in place of `"-*-"` than in the model number in the original list?

Comment: no list 2 contains "-*-" as given in the example. I'll have to write additional logic for this.

Comment: @piqueblinders How exactly do you want the comparison of the model names to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first flatten the nested lists and extract the names of the car models from the list as a `HashSet`. :

```
Set<String> names = carDataList.stream()
      .flatMap(cd -> cd.getCarDetails().stream())
      .flatMap(det -> det.getCars().stream())
      .map(Car::getModelName())
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

You can now use this set's `contains()` method to filter your `List<CarModel>`:

```
models.stream()
     .filter(model -> names.contains(model.getModel()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
     .forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.getModel()));
```

If you just want the names in the list:

```
models.stream()
    .map(CarModel::getModel)
    .filter(names::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be easier to store the modelName as a regex or to process it to use it as a regex (for instance, `BMW-500-7S-(.*)-Z100` instead of `BMW-500-7S-*-Z100`

Assuming we use the regex like this, we could use a stream to iterate on all modelNames and filter carModels that are not in the carData :

```
List<String> modelNames = carData.getCarDetails().stream()
                                                 .flatMap(e -> e.getCars().stream())
                                                 .map(Car::getModelName)
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
List<CarModel> result = carModels.stream()
                                 .filter(carModel ->                                  
                                             modelNames.stream()
                                                       .anyMatch(name -> name.matches(carModel.getModel()))
                                 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<CarModel> list1 = List.of(
    new CarModel("2019", "BMW-500-7S-150-Z100"),
    new CarModel("2019", "MERCEDES-700-7S-350-Z100"),
    new CarModel("2018", "AUDI-100-Q6-350-Z100"));

List<CarData> list2 = List.of(
    new CarData(OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 2, 6), LocalTime.of(0, 0), ZoneOffset.UTC),
        List.of(new CarDetails("John", List.of(
            new Car("BMW-500-7S-*-Z100", "Nevada"),
            new Car("MERCEDES-700-7S-*-Z100", "Daytona"))))));

Pattern models = Pattern.compile(list2.stream()
    .flatMap(d -> d.getCarDetails().stream())
    .flatMap(d -> d.getCars().stream())
    .map(c -> c.getModelName().replaceAll("\\*", ".*"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));

List<CarModel> result = list1.stream()
    .filter(m -> models.matcher(m.getModel()).matches())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

output:

```
[CarModel [year=2019, model=BMW-500-7S-150-Z100], CarModel [year=2019, model=MERCEDES-700-7S-350-Z100]]
```